# Knockout observables and performances

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

I’m working with knockout for more than 1 year now, but there is still a problem I cannot resolve. 
This is more “syntax sugar” problem, than actual problem. The code simples are in TypeScript, but it should be ok, even if you’ve never hear of it.

Let me explain.

Let’s say we we have an observable array ( MyArray) , where each element has “Value” observable. We want to create a computed observable to get a sum of all.

The evident approach is :

```
public SommeOne = ko.pureComputed((): number => {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.MyArray().length; i++) {
        res += this.MyArray()[i].Value();
    }
    return res;
});
```

But in this case, the call to this.MyArray() is evaluated twice on each iteration. And “Value” once. Which is OK for small arrays (less than 1000 elements), but become a problem for bigger arrays. So, so far my solution is :

```
public SommeOne = ko.pureComputed((): number => {
    var res = 0;
    var array = this.MyArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        res += array[i].Value();
    }
    return res;
});
```

At this point we evaluate Array function only once (Still 1 evaluation for Value, but it’s ok, we need this) and it works fine.

So the final question:

How can I implement second solution without creating an intermediary “array” ?

It is fine for one array, but if you need to do subtraction between two arrays, or something more complex, this is getting out of hand fast.

Comment: You can experiment with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or equivalent functions in [lodash](https://lodash.com/): `this.MyArray().reduce((res, it) => res + it.Value(), 0)`.  However, keep in mind that performance optimizations are not always intuitive, and native `Array#reduce` can be expensive. Profile your code to see where the slow spots are before making extensive changes.

Comment: Hmm, I haven’t heard about this library.
It seems to me like a way to go. My call to array will be evaluated only once. It will work awesome for simple cases, but it will fail if I need intersection or data gathering between two or more arrays. 
As for profiling, I’m doing it, just today, switched all Date.parse to Date.parseExact, gains are huge (A lot of data, a lot of everything). 
You can post this as answer, it will be my starting point.

Comment: You can post a self-answer together with a jsPerf benchmark once you make the decision

Comment: All solutions presented are O(n), so I'd go with what's most readable.  (In my opinion, _.reduce)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost certainly wasting your time worrying about these sort of optimizations.  Calling `this.myArray()` isn't doing any significant calculation.  Copying straight from the [knockout source code](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/observable.js), the logic that executes when invoking an observable or an observable array is as follows:

```
function observable() {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        // Write
        //[Omitted since not relevant here]
    }
    else {
        // Read
        ko.dependencyDetection.registerDependency(observable);
        return _latestValue;
    }
}
```

Other than the overhead of the function invocation and the small amount of work done by the dependency detection (which is likely basically just a `noop` function when you aren't calling from within a computed); the observable function just returns a reference to the array or whatever object it happens to be holding at the moment, and there's *very* little cost for an object reference.

The length of the array simply isn't a factor.  It doesn't "become a problem with bigger arrays", (at least the knockout part doesn't; the rest of the algorithm might depending on what you're doing) , and your caching of a value that knockout has already cached certainly isn't going to be a major performance gain.  (It probably won't make it worse either; though I'd consider it a hit to readability since it's introducing new variables)

As with any performance question; the standard disclaimers apply: you should only be concerned with this if you've demonstrated first that this is an area of the code that needs optimization, and secondly that it's this knockout invocation that is a significant performance issue.  If that's your situation, sure you can do some benchmarking to see if caching the value improves your performance any, but based on how you phrased your question it seems that there is a more basic misunderstanding here.

Comment: This recent blog post (http://mrale.ph/blog/2014/12/24/array-length-caching.html) is about a similar optimization; and shows the sort of unintuitive pitfalls to these sorts of attempted optimizations.

Comment: Great article, but as the author points out: it's only about V8; and personally wouldn't be too sure about whether IE & Moz FF JS engines compile with the same efficiency

Comment: @Tyblitz; sure but I don't think the point of the article is to make a specific argument about a specific case (`array.length` caching vs not) but to serve as a cautionary tale against these sort of optimizations in general.

Comment: I accept this as an answer, but actually I greatly simplified my question. This technic fails apart when there is a lots of computed (with multiple layers) involved. I was hoping to find a “magical” solution. But apparently there is none. After profiling: 95% of time is spent in “Array.IndexOf” function in knockout library. So overhead is not as small as you imagine.

Comment: @Jurion As you can see by looking at the source I quoted, there's no usage of `indexOf` when you read from `this.MyArray()` (or from write to it, for that matter), which was the subject of your question.  You might have an optimization issue, but it's *not* caused by reading and writing to the observable.